# Вывод в одну строку forEach jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Как можно сделать чтобы переменные выводились не с новой строки, а в одну строку?

```
<c:forEach items="${arr}" var="url">
  ${url}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: У вас url'ы в массиве содержат переносы строк?

Comment: Нет конечно. Просто в одной строчке будет много урлов.

Comment: тогда в чем проблема выводить в одну строку?

Comment: Это часть кода. Так же в for еach у меня будут c:url которые я в бэкенде не смогу получить
Через js делаю строку её и вывожу. Единственное решение как я увидел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно делать конкат строк в массиве и потом использовать значение переменной, например:

```
<c:forEach items="${arr}" var="arrUrl">
    <c:set var="url" value="${url}${arrUrl}"/>
</c:forEach>
<c:out value="${url}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно убрать переносы строк внутри исходного кода:

```jsp
<c:forEach items="${arr}" var="url">${url}</c:forEach>
```